# Validate Pandas dataframe column based on hierarchy

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Site': ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6","S7","S8","S9"],  
                'Sitelink': [" ","S1","S2","S6","S4"," ","S8"," ","S7"],  
                   'level': ["R", "T", "P", "T", "P", "R","T","R","P"],                     
                  'Weight':["55","55","55","85","85","80","150","190","200"]})
```

column 'Site' will be always unique

column 'Sitelink' captures the next lower level site to each Site

column 'level' has 3 values- R, T, P where the hierarchy is  R < T < P.

column 'Weight' can be any value.

The output should satisfy the condition that weight of a higher level site should be always lesser than or equal to lower level site. Expected result dataframe should be like

[image: Output Dataframe]

I'm trying to loop the dataframe and compare each site with next level. Is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: why row number 5 S5 S4 , value is equal , but return the error

Comment: @W-B Yes, you're right. Corrected the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you would like to to check if for each row the weight of the site is lower than or equal to the weight of the site marked as the *Sitelink*.

The code for a single row would than be:

```
def is_error(row):
    if row['Sitelink'] == " ":
        return 'No Error'
    site_link = df.loc[df['Site'] == row['Sitelink']]
    if int(row['Weight']) <= int(site_link['Weight']):
        return 'No Error'
    else:
        return 'Higher than lower'
```

Therefore we could apply this line for each row using the `apply` function:

```
df['Error'] = df.apply(is_error, axis=1)
```